# How to write a function to take something out of a generic?

Tags: c#, generics

I am doing an assignment where you make a distribution company and have to add/remove food and chemical items from the company ledger. I wrote the add sections through generics but I am having  difficulties with the remove part. I do not know how to write the logic for the remove items part where the user enter an item to remove and then if it matches it will remove it.

```
{
    class Product : Food, Cleaner
    {
        public string food { get; set; }
        public string cleaner { get; set; }

        public string foodRemover { get; set; }
        public string cleanerRemover { get; set; }
        public void GenericMethod<T>(T param)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        public class Food<T>
        {
            public T food { get; set; }
            public T doFood (T f)
            {
                return f;
            }
        }
        public class Cleaner<T>
        {
            public T cleaner { get; set; }
            public T doCleaner(T c)
            {
                return c;
            }
        }
        public void addFood()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Food:");
            Food<string> food1 = new Food<string>();
            Console.Write(food1.doFood("Pizza"));
            Food<int> food1index = new Food<int>() { food = 1 };
            Console.Write(food1index.doFood(1));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Food<string> food2 = new Food<string>();
            Console.Write(food2.doFood("Pasta"));
            Food<int> food2index = new Food<int>() { food = 2 };
            Console.Write(food2index.doFood(2));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Food<string> food3 = new Food<string>();
            Console.Write(food3.doFood("Sushi"));
            Food<int> food3index = new Food<int>() { food = 3 };
            Console.Write(food3index.doFood(3));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        public void removeFood(Food removeFood)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter food name you want to remove");
            foodRemover = Console.ReadLine();
            if (foodRemover == )
            {

            }

        }
        public void addCleaner()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cleaners:");
            Cleaner<string> cleaner1 = new Cleaner<string>();
            Console.Write(cleaner1.doCleaner("Baking soda"));
            Cleaner<int> cleanerindex1 = new Cleaner<int>();
            Console.Write(cleanerindex1.doCleaner(1));
            Cleaner<string> cleaner2 = new Cleaner<string>();
            Console.Write(cleaner2.doCleaner("Mouth wash"));
            Cleaner<int> cleanerindex2 = new Cleaner<int>();
            Console.Write(cleanerindex2.doCleaner(2));
            Cleaner<string> cleaner3 = new Cleaner<string>();
            Console.Write(cleaner3.doCleaner("Toothpaste"));
            Cleaner<int> cleanerindex3 = new Cleaner<int>();
            Console.Write(cleanerindex3.doCleaner(3));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        public void removeCleaner(Cleaner removeCleaner)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter food name you want to remove");
            cleanerRemover = Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the method is supposed to do. I'd recommend not including the rest of the code in the question because it's confusing to look at but isn't relevant. What do you want to remove from what?

Comment: I want to remove it from the addFood() and addCleaner() functions. I am guessing there is no container where it is stored so there is no point of entry to remove it? I want to remove it from what I added in those functions by the user typing the word or index and then it will delete the entry from the console.

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track. You can't remove it from a function - that doesn't really make sense. But if you've stored values in something (like a list or array?) then you could delete values from that.

Comment: You can not remove something, which does not exists anymore. Take a look at scopes of a variable https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/